# In CLion, can you start a build on a specific file?

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm doing some refactoring (more than what CLion can do automatically) and making lots of changes.  When I change a header file, it prompts a significant fraction of my project to rebuild, but I know the error messages will always come from the same spot (which unfortunately starts with "w").

Is there any way to control where CLion will start building so I don't have to wait 30s+ to get the next error message?

I've been typing `make src/workflow.o` in a console (I tried using the CLion console, but that doesn't make links from errors), but I'd rather have the direct links to the error location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another cmake target to build only the stuff you need.

See e.g. here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html?origin=old_help